# How to search a directory path within a file using vi editor

Tags: editor, vi

I want  to search for a directory path within a file in vi editor. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Using CentOS Linux 8.5 with vim 8.0, I was able to search a path within a text file edited via "vi myFile.txt" by escaping the path delimiter "/" with a "" character.  Example: To look for /var/lib within myFile.txt, I run "vi myFile.txt" and in the editing session enter:  `\/var\/lib`.